# FFMpeg to resize any video to fit 1080x1920 vertical, without cropping, instead by shrinking and adding blurred borders?

Tags: ffmpeg

I found some posts explaining how to turn any video horizontal by adding blurred borders using FFMpeg, but I want to convert videos to vertical 1080x1920. I don't want it to enlarge the video, nor crop if a dimension is bigger than either 1080 or 1920 dimension. Instead, I want it to shrink the video until it fits fully inside 1080x1920, and then I want it to add blurred borders to the empty areas.

This is the snippet I found, but when I tried reversing the numbers, it actually cropped the video.

`ffmpeg -I input.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v]scale=1920*2:1080*2,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=-1:1080[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=w=1920:h=1080" output.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple method:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]boxblur=40,scale=1080x1920,setsar=1[bg];[0:v]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=y=(H-h)/2" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

"Simple" because it forces the background to 1080x1920 and ignores aspect ratio. So the background it will looked stretched, but it is blurred so much nobody will care or notice.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting `Stream map '0:a' matches no streams`... do I ignore it?

Comment: @Max See updated answer. I assumed you had audio in the input.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that was referencing audio. Thanks. Is there any modification that will use the audio if it exists?

Comment: @Max It will automatically choose an audio if it exists.